How to capacitively couple an emitter follower to a load without losing most power?
As an exercise, I'm designing a circuit that takes a 7 MHz input signal (1V amplitude) with a source impedance of 1K and uses it to power a 50 ohm load.
I used an emitter follower, and it works well when DC coupled:


It loses some amplitude, but I'll accept that for now.
When I try to AC couple it, it fails completely:

Power to the load drops by about 100x:

How do I capacitively couple such a circuit without losing most of the power?

Update
Thank you to RussellH for posting a modification.  It still, however, only gets 5 mW into the load - less than 1% of the power of the DC coupled circuit!
I also experimented with the design below, which manages to get 50 mW into the load - better, but still far below the DC coupled 600 mW.


Try with a much lower R7

@TyassinYes, I tried that: power on the load drops to 2mW max with R7 10 Ohms.

You’re running into the reason why Class B and Class AB amplifiers exist. Class A won’t cut it for this type of load.

@SteKulov Can you elaborate? I though the benefit of Class B was efficiency, but if you're willing to pay the price, and bias Class A, you can still get full output power.  At least that's how I've seen it.

@SRobertJames: How much power is full power?

@RussellH The DC coupled circuit pushes 250 mW of signal power into the load (plus another 350 mW of wasted power).

The emitter current must remain the same before and after capacitive coupling. So R7 should be 50 ohms. The ac load then is 25 ohms.
So a drop in ac output is to be expected depending on the source resistance reflected into the emitter.
The ac load will demand more current than before, so current saturation will occur at a lower input voltage.
You may get a better simulation by choosing a real transistor, with a known high β, than using the generic one.
Edit:
Here is my simulation. I ac coupled the original circuit with a 1uF and 10K to display without dc offset.

Edit:
I think you are calculating the power incorrectly. Referring to the clip from your upper simulation, the ac voltage across the load is about 1.2V peak-to-peak. So the rms voltage is 0.424V. Thus the signal power to the load is \$\frac{V^2_{rms}}{50}=3.6mW\$ not 50mW or 250mW or 600mW. The dc and ac power must be calculated independently. In your case the dc power into RE is \$\frac{V^2_{ave}}{50}\approx \frac{4.8^2}{50}\approx 460.8mW\$. So the efficiency is almost 0%. The combined power in RE is \$P\text{total}=\sqrt{V^2_{dc}+V^2_{rms}}\$
So @Ste Kulov's comment:

You’re running into the reason why Class B and Class AB amplifiers exist. Class A won’t cut it for this type of load.

is very appropriate.


Setting R7 to 50 ohms only gives load power of 5mW.

My simulation seems reasonable. I did not calculate output power. Use a real transistor.

Your left hand circuit is not the same as the one in the question. The 10k and 50 ohm resistors are swapped. That is why you don't get the clipping. Beta has nothing to do with the clipping.

Look carefully at the electronics @MathKeepsMeBusy Without the 10k and 1uF they are the same. The high pass is just used to comparatively display.

In the original question, the 10k is the emitter resistor, directly connected between emitter and ground, and the 50 ohm is connected via capacitor to the emitter. In your schematic these are reversed. That is why you get no clipping. (It's 1k in the original).

Ok. I think I see what you are doing. Your "original" is the first circuit in the question, not the problematic circuit in the question. Carry on.

Correct, @MathKeepsMeBusy

Your simulation agrees with mine: 0.5V * 10mA = 5mW.  The DC coupled circuit has 600mW.  My question remains: How can I AC couple without loosing 90% of the power?

@SRobertJames: I don't know where 90% comes from. There is no reference in the question on how the power loss is calculated. Nor is there an expectation for power output. For the two circuit that I presented the power difference in the load before and after is only 22%, (3.6mW to 2.8mW). There has to be a loss because the ac current divides between the emitter resistor and the load resistor. My answer addresses the power loss from changing the bias point resulting in clipping if the waveform. If you have more to share, then make an edit to the question.

Sorry for not being clearer.  Can you see the graph of the DC circuit? It shows 600 mW of power into the load.  Of that, 350 mW is waste but 250 mW is the signal.

@SRobertJames - You do not really get the mentioned 600mW output power. The usable (AC) output power is at best 10mW and the rest, about 500mW, stems from the DC current flowing through the load and wasted as heat.

@Raonoke Wow - can you explain that.  I see how 350mW is wasted, but since the rest varies at the signal frequency, why do you consider it wasted? E.g. if the load is an antenna, won't it see 350 mW at the signal frequency?

See my last edit @SRobertJames.

Got it! Unlike current, power is not linear and does not obey superposition.

@SRobertJames - The AC voltage at the DC coupled 50 Ohm load can not be more than 1V peak which means less than 10mW you can use further down the line. The almost 100mA DC current through the 50 Ohm load is generating (unusable) 500mW heat in the load. Please note there are additional 500mW wasted as heat (mainly) in the transistor.


How to capacitively couple an emitter follower to a load without [losing] most power?

You can't. Most of the power in this circuit will become heat.
Unfortunately, an emitter follower with capacitor coupling and no clipping is inherently inefficient. That is one reason why push-pull configurations are commonly used for emitter followers when efficiency is a concern.
At best, with a sine wave input to an emitter follower, with no clipping, and capacitor coupled output, one loses about half the power in the transistor, and about half of the remaining power in emitter resistor. The losses can be rearranged a bit by increasing the emitter resistor while decreasing the input signal, but that really doesn't buy you any more efficiency.
If efficiency is a major concern for your application, seek an alternative circuit topology, such as push-pull, or, if the situation permits, a class D amplifier. Both of these alternatives are more complex than your circuit, but the inefficiency of your circuit is a big part of why these alternatives are used.

The combination of \$R_{SRC}\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ cause an attenuation by about \$\frac{2}{3}\$. Measure the signal at the base to see this.
This corresponds to over 50% power loss even before the emitter follower.
Either reduce \$R_{SRC}\$, or increase \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ to improve this. Then employ the solution proposed by RussellH (add \$R_E=50\Omega\$ between emitter and ground) to mitigate clipping.

The attenuation of Src is only 2/3, not enough to cause a 90%+ power drop.  More importantly, while increase R4 and R5 reduce attenuation, like you suggest, power to the load is still miniscule.
